# How to display number with space between thousands?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to display number 1000000 as 1 000 000?
I've tried all the custom formating, but nothing helped. 
This: #,##0 make 1,000,000 ... but I would like to have only space.
I cannot find proper answer on google as well.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the cell or row you want to format > Format Cells > Custom

```
### ### ###
```

and on the Thai keyboard

```
###\ ###\ ###
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for help, but that doesn't make anything. the Number is still same, without any change.

Comment: Working on o365 and excel 2010 on my end, does =(TEXT(I1,"### ### ###")) work for you.. I1 being your number

Comment: No, it doesn't work, still showing 1000000 ...

Comment: Upload a screenshot of your worksheet to the question

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IRUzSqF.png

Comment: There looks to be some other formatting that cell, try using another row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103759/discussion-between-sqltemp-and-slunicko).

Comment: If `I1` is formatted as left justified text, you might get weird "non-function", try adding a `VALUE()` around `I1` in the TEXT()-formula.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting command: ###\ ###\ ### worked well, with Thai keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the number you are looking is being considered as text by Excel. In the screen cap below A1 & A2 have the same format. I entered A1 as text (single quote before the number), A2 is A1*1 (see the formula bar) converting it to a number.  So the # ### ### format works in A2, but not A1.

[image]

Hopefully, this helps.